# Making a column unique with one exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have an application whose work flow involves submitting information to an outside group and then inputting the user's id number into the system.

For that reason we allow a set default value `"00000000"` to be put into the id field as a tentative value before the entry is approved and a permanent one is put in.

What I'm looking for is essentially a way to ensure that the column remains `unique` **except for that one value**.

What I'm basically looking for is a `UNIQUE` constraint, however instead of `NULL` being the blank option it being `"00000000"`. I've considered doing it as part of a `CHECK` constraint, however that seems like it'd be a big performance hit. (Under the assumption that UNIQUE does some kind of indexing)

Comment: allow nulls and treat nulls as incomplete, use a check constraint, or maybe an instead of insert trigger (i hate triggers)

Comment: See filtered Indexes: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/344/indexes/23954/partial-or-filtered-index#t=20161013174245878339

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **Filtered Index**

as the Following:-

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_yourcolumn_notspecificvalue
ON YourTable(yourcolumn)
WHERE yourcolumn != "00000000";
```

**Example:**

```
-- Create Table
Create table Test (id int identity, code varchar (100))

-- Create Unique Filtered  Index
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_MyCol_Filtered 
ON Test(code)
WHERE code != '00000000';

-- Insert Dumy Data >> '00000000' is repeated and '0101' is once
insert into Test (code) 
Values  ('00000000'),
        ('00000000'),
        ('00000000'),
        ('0101')


select * from Test
```

**The Result:**

[image]

```
-- Now try inserting '0101' again
insert into Test (code) Values ('0101')
```

**The Result:**

[image]

---

For more details:
[Create Filtered Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Approving the user entry through work flow sound like very crucial business logic. I would like to suggest that generate random but unique (like time stamp) number and insert with new user entry. Keep additional column which differentiate ( flag) approved entries from unapproved entries. Once the user gets approval from work flow, update the id and flag.